# How to move cursor in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

EDIT:

okay, i have checked the code and its rendering out by a jquery widget.

END

I am trying to move the cursor to `<a \>`, but the problem is that the element is not rendered until i move mouse pointer physically on selected image.

How can i move to the mouse to hover over `<a \>` to select/click?

```
FF version 20
Selenium WebDriver version: 2.31.2.0
```

Current code

```java
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

 int locationX = Convert.ToInt32(ratingElementDiv[i].Location.X);
 int locationY = ratingElementDiv[i].Location.Y;

 actions.MoveToElement(WaitForElement(By.CssSelector(starElement)), locationX, locationY).Click().Perform();
```

i dont see any action happening... any help?

Comment: Is the hover event triggered by a CSS :hover event?  If so are you using a non-native events (e.g. FireFox in OSX).  If the answer to the two previous questions is yes you are stuck, JavaScript cannot trigger a CSS :hover event you need a native implementation.

Comment: 1+ thanks for the info, i have to check to see if the hovering is happening in css, i will get back to you.

Comment: okay, i have checked the code and its rendering out by a jquery widget... so in this case what should i be doing?

Comment: Is the page publicly visible?

Comment: no its not unfortunate

Comment: Can you supply an HTML snippet of the image you are hovering over with its associated CSS?

Answer (score 8):

Action is composed by 3 steps.

- configuration

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Point location ratingElementDiv[i].getLocation(); 
builder.MoveToElement(WaitForElement(By.CssSelector(starElement)), location.X, location.Y).click();
```

(i'm not sure about the click)

- get the action

```
Action selectLink = builder.build();
```

- execution

```
selectLink.perform();
```

try this and tell me if you still have some problem.

Comment: error: on builder.Build() -  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.IAction' to 'System.Action'`

Comment: I use `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` i can't help you more i don't really know something about jquery ;(

Comment: is it possible to have the html ?

Answer (score 4):

This link will help you. It explain both keyboard and mouse event.

http://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html

Comment: That link is helpful but an additional quick summary in your answer would be very helpful to the reader

Answer (score 3):

Lets say when you click "Select Your Test" you see a dropdown of multiple elements(ABC, DEF, GHI, etc ). You want to select ABC and click it. Use following.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Select Your Test")).click();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("ABC"))).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

it works to me

```
//定位一個按鈕
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='page-button']"));
//new 一個移動滑鼠的物件
Actions clickAction = new Actions(driver).click(button);
//執行
clickAction.build().perform();
```